# Verifying the correctness of KKT conditions

Tags: linear-programming, kkt-conditions

I have a LP problem and derived the corresponding KKT conditions for the same. I simulated the LP and obtained the primal and dual values and manually checked if the KKT conditions hold. Is there any other way to check the correctness of KKT conditions?

Comment: What do you mean by "check the correctness"? The KKT conditions tell you whether a given point $x$ satisfies the necessary conditions of optimality, therefore you need a point $x$ to check them. You could however simply solve your LP (e.g. using simplex or barrier methods) and those are guaranteed (providing a good implementation and not awful numerics) to yield the optimal solution (and hence satisfy the KKT conditions).